# What does the error message "all endpoints are disconnected" mean from mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

Does anyone know the meaning of the info message 
"all endpoints are disconnected, detected by connect check (1), cping (0), send (0)"

This occurs with some regularity in my mod_jk log, but I can't find information about whether this is a problem, or just something to ignore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that tomcat has shut down the socket due to the soTimeout parameter of the AJP connector. mod_jk is going to reconnect next, therefore this is merely an [info] message. If the reconnect fails, an [error] will be logged.
So this is entirely harmless.